# Select elements between two defined elements

Tags: css

I am trying to select elements between two defined elements, for example I have a ul element with many li elements as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li id="title1">Firt Tittle</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li id="title2">Second Tittle</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
     .....
    <li>..</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to select li tags from 1 to 5, I used `#title1 ~ li:not[id]` But this selector will be select all 3 unnecessary li tags from 6 to 8. Any suggest or help, thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Selector for nth range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639247/css-selector-for-nth-range)

Comment: Not possible unless the number of items between is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case where you know the structure of your DOM, you can use a mix between the css rule `:nth-last-child()`, `:nth-child()` and `:not()` like that:

```css
ul li:not(#title1):not(#title2):nth-child(n+1):nth-last-child(n+5) {
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="title1">Firt Tittle</li>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li id="title2">Second Tittle</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
```