# Error on .text.strip() using Selenium BeautifulSoup for Web-scraping (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** the price from a webpage. Firstly, I have written the code of the price by block before I merge it altogether in one code. It works well when I written  it by block. (especially for the price part on using `.text.strip()`

```
!pip install selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.fashionvalet.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=duck"

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/header/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div')
btn.click()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice > strong').text.strip()
#"strong").select_one("strong").text.strip()
print(p_price)
```

> MYR50.00

Unfortunately, when I merge all the code, the error come from the `.text.strip()`on the price part,

```
!pip install selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_url(product_name):
    
    product_name = product_name.replace(' ', '+')
    url_template = "https://www.fashionvalet.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={}"
    url = url_template.format(product_name)
    return url 

def product_info(card):
    
    # name 
    p_name = card.find('h3').text.strip()
    
    # price
    
    #p_rice = card.find("p", "fvPLPProductPrice").select("strong")
    p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice > strong').text.strip()
    
    # image
    p_image = card.find('img')
    p_img = p_image['src']
    
    # brand
    p_brand = card.find('p', "fvPLPProductBrand").text.strip()
    
    # discount percent
    p_dis = card.find('p', "fvPLPProductMeta").text.strip()
    
    info = (p_name, p_price, p_img, p_brand, p_dis)
    return info 

def main(product):
    
    records = []
    url = get_url(product) # 1--generate URL 
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver.exe') # 2--open browser
    driver.get(url) # 3--open URL 
    
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    # BUTTON
    btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/header/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div')
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(5)
               
    # AUTO-SCROLLING 
    # -- make the parsing time of python is equivalent to the web 
    temp_height=0
 
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
        time.sleep(10)
        check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;")
        if check_height==temp_height:
            break
        temp_height=check_height
    
    time.sleep(5)
    # AUTO-SCROLL end
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    product_card = soup.select('.fvPLPProducts > li')
    
    for allproduct in product_card:
        productDetails = product_info(allproduct)
        records.append(productDetails)
    
    col = ['Name', 'Price', 'Image', 'Brand', 'Discount']
    
    all_data = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=col)
    
    all_data.to_csv('D:\\FASHION-{}.csv'.format(product))
```

This is the output, after I ran `main("duck")` the error come out like this,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7b75c58eb0da> in <module>
----> 1 main("duck")

<ipython-input-6-7d068e5049f6> in main(product)
     70 
     71     for allproduct in product_card:
---> 72         productDetails = product_info(allproduct)
     73         records.append(productDetails)
     74 

<ipython-input-6-7d068e5049f6> in product_info(card)
     20 
     21     #p_rice = card.find("p", "fvPLPProductPrice").select("strong")
---> 22     p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice > strong').text.strip()
     23 
     24     # image

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text
`
```

I have tried to remove the `text.strip()`, it works well, but the output is including the tag from the HTML code which is not what I want.

As conclusion, the `.text.strip()` is worked when separate the code, but it become error as I merge it all.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the website's HTML, we'll find that there are two types of "item prices" (the output you're looking for), one price that's *on sale* and another that's not.

You are *only* searching for tags that are *on sale* (the right one in the image below, but not the left one).

[image]

You can use the `,` CSS selector to search for *both* types of tags.

Instead of:

```
p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice > strong').text.strip()
```

use:

```
p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice strong, li:nth-of-type(n+3) p.fvPLPProductPrice').text.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried exactly your code, but it still show the same Attribute Error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. And fyi, I have tried also using your code by block, its not showing both type of tags, but only the non-strikethrough price.

Comment: @xkderhaka Are you using `duck` as the query, `main("duck")`? Also, is there a reason that you're using Selenium and not only beautifulsoup? I tried with just beautifulsoup and it worked

Comment: I have tried it again, and changing the n+3 into n+2 and it works!. Anyway, can you explain what is `li:nth-of-type(n+3)` code meaning to?

Comment: @MndelIG yes there are reasons why I used Selenium as the page is used JS or something to hide the information inside the card. But then connecting the BS4 and Selenium as I have comfortable with BS4. The Selenium is just a door to access into the page and also for autmation.

Comment: @xkderhaka The `li:nth-of-type(n+3)` selects every third `li` onword See the docs for [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061560/12349734) SO post (it's a bit different)

Comment: and also, why my previous code `p_price = card.select_one('.fvPLPProductPrice > strong').text.strip()` is show an error? What is the problem by this code?

Comment: @xkderhaka Because That was looking for a `strong` tag, but the strikethrough elements don't have a `strong` tag, so it's calling `.text` on nothing, since there's no match